# Proving that a set is an ultrafilter.

Tags: general-topology, filters, infinitary-combinatorics, compactification

A sequence of ultrafilters of $\omega$ (therefore each $p_n \in \beta \omega$) $p_n$ is discrete if there exists a sequence $X_n$ of subsets of $\omega$ such that for each $n$, $X_n \in p_n$ and if $n \neq m$ then $X_n\cap X_m=\emptyset$.

Let $p_n$ be a discrete sequence of ultrafilters on $\omega$. Let $q \in \text{cl} \{p_n: n \in \omega\}$. Then we define $\Omega(p, q)=\{A\subset \omega: \forall B \in q \exists n \in A(B \in p_n)\}$.

I must show that $r=\Omega(p, q)$ is an ultrafilter. Clearly, $\emptyset \notin r$ and $r$ is upward closed and since $q \in \text{cl} \{p_n: n \in \omega\}$ it follows that $\omega \in \Omega(p, q)$

More details: Given $A \subset \omega$

It remains to see that $r$ is closed under finite intersections and that the filter is maximal. Can someone help?

Comment: Where did you see this? If this is a homework assignment, what are the references for the course?